# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): navigate is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): navigate is not a function
> addProductHandler
> */react_client/src/scenes/screens/AddProduct.jsx:37

This is the error code I receive after adding a product and then to navigate to an URL.
Happened after migrating to newer versions of dependencies.

Everything else works, but not this.

Code

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Container, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const AddProduct = ({ navigate }) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
    const [published, setPublished] = useState(true)
    const [image, setImage] = useState('')

    const addProductHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('image', image)
        formData.append('title', title)
        formData.append('price', price)
        formData.append('description', description)
        formData.append('published', published)

        await axios.post('/api/products/addProduct', formData)
        navigate('/products')
    }

   
export default AddProduct
```

New dependencies

```json
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router": "^6.16.0",
"react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

It will add the product, but not redirect to the url defined.

Answer (score 0):

The error is informing you that the `navigate` prop isn't a function. This means you are either passing an undefined value or something *other than* a `function`.

The `react-router-dom` `navigate` function doesn't need to be passed like this though, `AddProduct` can, and *should*, import and use the `useNavigate` hook.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AddProduct = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  const addProductHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('published', published);

    await axios.post('/api/products/addProduct', formData);
    navigate('/products');
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
}

export default AddProduct;
```